# Lates version of "implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android""

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin

what is the latest version of-" implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:""

i am learning about android and kotlin and working of APIs  and this came as an error . so i want to know  the latest version of the dependencies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello bro this dependencies latest version :

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.0"
```

Comment: i am asking for this "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:". The error my project shows is "Unresolved reference: features" and "Unresolved reference: JsonFeature"